# How do responses to Likert type response scales vary across countries and cultures?

Tags: measurement, cross-cultural-psychology, attitudes

I gave [an answer here on stats.stackexchange.com about how to analyse ordinal items](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8995/183), such as those on [Likert type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) response scales (e.g., Strongly disagree to Strongly agree).
Someone asked whether there were differences between countries and cultures in how respondents use such scales. I remember reading research about this many years ago. I can remember something about certain countries preferring extreme responses. Such differences naturally have implications for cross-cultural comparisons of levels of like life satisfaction, personality, and presumably any self-report measure that uses such response scales.

#### Questions

- How does use of Likert type response scales vary across countries and cultures?
- What explains any such differences?
- How are differences in response style differentiated from differences in levels of the underlying construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Culture reference effects

Heine et al (2002) discuss how people in different cultures often answer questions relative to a reference group in their own culture. Thus, for example, if a culture is  more collectivistic in general, measured cultural differences may less when people within a culture answer test items  relative to their own cultural reference group.

To quote the abstract:

> Social comparison theory maintains that people think about themselves
>   compared with similar others. Those in one culture, then, compare
>   themselves with different others and standards than do those in
>   another culture, thus potentially confounding cross-cultural
>   comparisons. A pilot study and Study 1 demonstrated the problematic
>   nature of this reference-group effect: Whereas cultural experts agreed
>   that East Asians are more collectivistic than North Americans,
>   cross-cultural comparisons of trait and attitude measures failed to
>   reveal such a pattern. Study 2 found that manipulating reference
>   groups enhanced the expected cultural differences, and Study 3
>   revealed that people from different cultural backgrounds within the
>   same country exhibited larger differences than did people from
>   different countries. Crosscultural comparisons using subjective Likert
>   scales are compromised because of different reference groups. Possible
>   solutions are discussed.

#### Cultural differences in response tendencies

Lee et al (2002) summarised some of the empirical literature on cross-cultural differences in use of response scales:

> Only a few researchers have addressed the issue of cultural
>   differences in rating scales empiri- cally. Wong, Tam, Fung, and Wan
>   (1993) found no difference in the way Chinese participants in Hong
>   Kong responded to an odd versus an even number of response choices.
>   Johnson (1981) found no difference in how readers of Horizons USA who
>   resided in Great Britain, Italy, the Philippines, and Venezuela
>   responded to bipolar scales. Stening and Everett (1984) found that
>   Japanese managers responding in Japanese were more likely to choose
>   the midpoint than were American or British managers responding in
>   English. Chen, Lee, and Stevenson (1995) found the same effect for
>   Japanese and to a lesser extent for Taiwanese in a sample comparing
>   11th-grade students in Japan, Taiwan, Canada, and, in the United
>   States, Minneapolis. Iwata, Saito, and Roberts (1994) and Iwata,
>   Roberts, and Kawa- kami (1995) reported that junior high school
>   students in Japan and the United States responded similarly on
>   negative items but that Japanese were less likely to endorse positive
>   items.

When reviewing the literature on cross-cultural differences in response style Hamamura et al (2008) stated that:

> Compared to North Americans of European-heritage, higher levels of
>   extreme responding have been observed in African–Americans (Bachman &
>   O’Malley, 1984) and Latino Americans (Hui & Triandis, 1989). In
>   contrast, East Asians seem to show more moderacy than samples of
>   European-heritage (Chen, Lee, & Stevenson, 1995)

#### References

- Bachman, J. G., & O’Malley, P. M. (1984). Yea-saying, nay-saying, and going to extremes: Black–white diﬀerences in
  response styles. Public Opinion Quarterly, 48, 491–509.
- Chen, C., Lee, S. Y., & Stevenson, H. W. (1995). Response style and cross-cultural comparisons of rating scales among
  East Asian and North American students. Psychological Science, 6, 170–175.
- Hamamura, T., Heine, S.J. & Paulhus, D.L. (2008). Cultural differences in response styles: The role of dialectical thinking. Personality and Individual Differences, 44, 932-942.
- Heine, S.J. and Lehman, D.R. and Peng, K. and Greenholtz, J. (2002). What's wrong with cross-cultural comparisons of subjective Likert scales?: The reference-group effect. *Journal of personality and social psychology, 82*, 903, [PDF](http://image.sciencenet.cn/olddata/kexue.com.cn/upload/blog/file/2009/3/2009318111257156614.pdf)
- Hui, C. H., & Triandis, H. C. (1989). Eﬀects of culture and response format on extreme response style. Journal of CrossCultural Psychology, 20, 296–309.
- Iwata, N., Roberts, C.R., & Kawakami, N. (1995).
  Japan–U.S. comparison of responses to depression
  scale items among adult workers. Psychiatry Research, 58, 237–245.
- Iwata, N., Saito, K., & Roberts, R.E. (1994). Responses
  to a self-administered depression scale among
  younger adolescents in Japan. Psychiatry Research,
  53, 275–287.
- Johnson, J.D. (1981). Effects of the order of presentation of evaluative dimensions for bipolar scales in
  four societies. Journal of Social Psychology, 113,
  21–27.
- Lee, J.W. and Jones, P.S. and Mineyama, Y. and Zhang, X.E. (2002). Cultural differences in responses to a Likert scale. Research in nursing & health, 25, 295-306.
- Stening, B.W., & Everett, J.E. (1984). Response styles
  in a cross-cultural managerial study. Journal of
  Social Psychology, 122, 151–156.
- Wong, C.S., Tam, K.C., Fung, M.Y., & Wan, K. (1993).
  Differences between odd and even number of
  response scale: Some empirical evidence. Chinese
  Journal of Psychology, 35, 75–86.